# Mysite implementation for the Global audience?

Tags: my-site, deployment

We have three sharepoint farms respectively in Asia, MiddleEast & Europe. We want to create the Mysites based on the conutry that users belongs to. I hope, it is possible through audience & trusted location settings. I wonder if we can have the same URL across the farms for Mysite especially in this case?

Let me know how to go about it if it's achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out the [planning site for My Sites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx) on technet?

Theres a lot of good info there.

Also there is a whitepaper on the subject [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd93bc74-d923-4dc9-b112-715d5ddb64fd&displaylang=en).

Basically what you do is setup 3 user profile service applications and define My Site Host locations with audiences that determine what My Site a user should be redirected to.

By using the [Replication Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663011.aspx) of the [SharePoint 2010 administration toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508849.aspx), it is possible to replicate user profiles across My Site hosts placed in different geographical locations for non-ad data (user data fields and Business Connectivity fields).

When replicating properties the engine also uses the My Site host locations list to find out what my site host is used by a user.

Comment: Still working on, will share my experience